# subsetMaf() query argumet can't get Shiny reactive value from webpage input.

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am doing some work to show a pic generated by maftools on web server, but it seems subsetMaf() "query" argument can't get a Shiny reactive value input from web server. Below is a simple test:
subsetMaf() works well on console on R like below:

#### read data

```
library(magrittr)
mc3_pass <- readr::read_rds(file.path(config$database, "TCGA", "snv", "snv_mutation_mc3_public.pass.filtered_maf-4cancers.rds.gz")) # test data include clinical data, which include a column called "cancer_types"
```

#### mc3_pass clinical data look like below, I want to filter cancer_types in clinical data

```
mc3_pass %>% maftools::getClinicalData()

    Tumor_Sample_Barcode cancer_types
1: TCGA-05-4244-01A-01D-1105-08         LUAD
2: TCGA-05-4249-01A-01D-1105-08         LUAD
3: TCGA-05-4250-01A-01D-1105-08         LUAD
4: TCGA-05-4382-01A-01D-1931-08         LUAD
5: TCGA-05-4384-01A-01D-1753-08         LUAD
---                                          
2245: TCGA-Z2-A8RT-06A-11D-A372-08         SKCM
2246: TCGA-Z2-AA3S-06A-11D-A397-08         SKCM
2247: TCGA-Z2-AA3V-06A-11D-A397-08         SKCM
2248: TCGA-Z7-A8R5-01A-42D-A41F-09         BRCA
2249: TCGA-Z7-A8R6-01A-11D-A41F-09         BRCA
```

#### console test works well

```
ct <- reactive({c("LUAD")}) # pre define a object stored a cancer type name like reactive value in shiny.
query = as.expression("cancer_types %in% isolate(ct())") # define a query for filter, isolate() used to get the value of reactive value on console.
maftools::subsetMaf(mc3_pass, query = query, mafObj = T) -> gene_list_maf # subsetMaf filter
gene_list_maf %>%
    maftools::getClinicalData() # check the filter results
```

#### Works well on console, cancer_types filter successfully as you can see below.

```
Tumor_Sample_Barcode cancer_types
1: TCGA-05-4244-01A-01D-1105-08 LUAD
2: TCGA-05-4249-01A-01D-1105-08 LUAD
3: TCGA-05-4250-01A-01D-1105-08 LUAD
4: TCGA-05-4382-01A-01D-1931-08 LUAD
5: TCGA-05-4384-01A-01D-1753-08 LUAD
508: TCGA-NJ-A55O-01A-11D-A25L-08 LUAD
509: TCGA-NJ-A55R-01A-11D-A25L-08 LUAD
510: TCGA-NJ-A7XG-01A-12D-A397-08 LUAD
511: TCGA-O1-A52J-01A-11D-A25L-08 LUAD
512: TCGA-S2-AA1A-01A-12D-A397-08 LUAD
```

#### shiny reactive value lead an error

before run code below, please delete objects generated before.

```
mc3_pass <- readr::read_rds(file.path(config$database, "TCGA", "snv", "snv_mutation_mc3_public.pass.filtered_maf-4cancers.rds.gz")) # test data include clinical data, which include a column called "cancer_types"
library(shiny)
Lung_choice <- list(
"Lung Adenocarcinoma(LUAD)" = "LUAD",
"Lung Squamous Cell Carcinoma(LUSC)" = "LUSC"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "select",label = "Select cancers",
choices = Lung_choice),
actionButton("go",label = "Go"),
shiny::textOutput(outputId = "table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
ct <- reactive({
input$select
})
observeEvent(input$go,{
print(ct())
print(class(ct()))
ct_2 <- as.character(ct())
print(ct_2)
# query = as.expression("cancer_types %in% ct()") # Error in ct: could not find function "ct"
# query = as.expression("cancer_types %in% ct_2") # Error in eval: object 'ct_2' not found
query = as.expression("cancer_types %in% input$select") # Error in eval: object 'input' not found
print(query)
maftools::subsetMaf(mc3_pass, query = query, mafObj = T) -> gene_list_maf # subsetMaf filter
print("maf done!")
gene_list_maf %>%
maftools::getClinicalData() %>%
dplyr::select(cancer_types) %>%
unique() %>% t() %>%
as.vector()->.x# check the filter results
print(".x done!")
output$table <- renderText({
return(.x)
})
print("out done!")
print(.x)
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)

# Below is output shows that object ct() and ct_2 exactly stored the value from webpage input
[1] "LUAD"
[1] "character"
[1] "LUAD"
expression("cancer_types %in% input$select")
Warning: Error in eval: object 'input' not found
Stack trace (innermost first):
75: eval
74: eval
73: [.data.table
72: [
71: maftools::subsetMaf
70: observeEventHandler [#14]
4: 
3: do.call
2: print.shiny.appobj
1:
```

I guess it is the problem of environment, but it is difficult for me to solve this problem, do you have any suggestion? Is there any way to solve this problem?
Thank you very much, any suggestion will be help.

Comment: Can you provide a sample data?

Comment: Oh yes, I put a .gz file on justbeamit , please see the link: https://justbeamit.com/7pata

Comment: The link you doesn't work..

Comment: Oh, my apologies, sorry for that. This link works: http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g05d52e66851f2bc51000048603fc4f3b83b5c380d1

Comment: I get and error `Error: 'getClinicalData' is not an exported object from 'namespace:maftools'` running the code `mc3_pass %>% maftools::getClinicalData()`.

Comment: What happened when you just run: `mc3_pass`, is it an object of class MAF? I download the data again and run `getClinicalData()` with no error happened. Or how did you read the data in? It is a rds type file, should use `readr::read_rds` to read in. Try this: `mc3_pass<-readr::read_rds("C:\\Users\\MyPC\\Desktop\\test_data.rds.gz")
library(maftools)
getClinicalData(mc3_pass)` I got no error with that.

Comment: Yes `mc3_pass` is objec of `MAF`. The error is that `maftools` does not have function `getClinicalData`. Which version of `maftools` package do you have? When I google it the function`getClinicalData` seems to be in `cgdsr` package.

Comment: The latest version, please see link as below: https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/maftools.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is `query = as.expression("cancer_types %in% input$select")`.

You can solve this problem by replacing the above code with:

```
query =  as.expression(paste0("cancer_types %in%'",input$select,"'"))
```

What we essentially get from `paste0("cancer_types %in%'",input$select,"'")` is 
 `expression("cancer_types %in%'LUAD'")`. Since `input$select` is not present in the local environment of `subsetMaf` function it was creating the error, and now with this change we are passing `'LUAD'`which is present in the dataset.

**EDIT:**

When the selected input is larger than one you can first combine the inputs and then pass it. The code would be as follows:

```
InpSel <-  paste0(input$select, collapse = "','")
query =  as.expression(paste0("cancer_types %in% c('",InpSel,"')"))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! It is really works when I do as you suggested, but there is another problem, subsetMaf can just deal with the first element of input$select. For example, when I select more than one choices on web, the output just give me the first element I selected. Because when the selected choices larger than 1, what we get from `as.expression(paste0("cancer_types %in%'",input$select,"'"))` is `expression("cancer_types %in%'LUAD'", "cancer_types %in%'LUSC', ...)`, but the subsetMaf can just use the first expression as it query arugument, so this is what the problem is.

Comment: @胡斐斐, I have edited the answer to handle cases when more than one choice is selected. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helps me.